# Fetch results based on parameter WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm attempting to customize a wordpress theme.  I've added custom field `cp_job` with form submission.  This indicates if the `ad` is either `Buyer`(Buying services) or `Seller`(selling services), which is now complete.

Now I want to fetch results based on `buyer` or `seller`.  In this wordpress theme classipress they have "Ads" on the side:

[image]

I simply want to fetch `ads` which have the attribute `buyer` or `seller`, which I assume is under the MySQL column `cp_job`.  These ads will return the `ad` with all columns.  Doing this in native PHP and MySQL would be easy but working around this theme/wordpress is way more complicated as I don't understand WordPress syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wordpress custom query to fetch record from any table.Like

```
global $wpdb;
// return array of object
$dataArr = $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT col FROM table WHERE cond = data ");
```

Then you can do foreach on records like below:

```
foreach( $dataArr as $data ){
    echo $data->col;
}
```

Hope this helps ;)
Cheers!!!